# prevent activity back to log in and log out button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i have an activity called logIn which leads to an activity called users not i want to prevent users activity from going back to the logIn activity so a added this code in the users activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

and it worked well but now i want the user to be able to log out so he could and go back to the log in activity in a button click, i added a button in users activity and added the onClickListener as below:

```
LogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Users.this, Login.class));

            }
        });
```

but when i add the onClickListener the application crash when i click the logIn button and does not go to the users activity.

any Tips? i tried to use finish() at the end of logIn activity but the app crash even without the listener.

edit:

i was missing the

```
final Button LogOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogOut);
```

problem solved

Comment: post the stack trace

Comment: `logIn.class` - you sure that is your Login Activity class and not your login button by any chance?

Comment: Murat, `i have an activity called logIn`

Comment: the activity also called logIn

Comment: `Follow these tips for better questions!`:  1) Only paste nesseccery relevant code. 2) Use proper gramma and spelling!! 3) Always post the stack trace!

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a way so that you are not finishing the login activity. You are not destroying it and keep it in the background. So that just when you want to go back to the login page write this code--

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logOut);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Users.this, logIn.class));
              finish();
         }
     });
```

So now when you destroy it the login page should come..

Comment: *i want to prevent users activity from going back to the logIn activity*

Comment: So just add this finish(); attribute to the login page . With a intent open up the User page and when loged out finish(); the user page and use an intent to come back to the login page.

Comment: the app crash when i add the onclick listener of the logout button i think it is because i cant put public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
} and than go back to it

Comment: If you post the full java code of the intent that you pass i may be able to spot the error

Comment: Please add the java code for the onclick listener aswell

Comment: Knatiic ok i will in couple of ours hope you be here when i put it

Comment: Actually i probably won't be as i will out for a competition at that time.

Comment: i added the whole code for the users activity if you can check it please

Comment: cant believe the problem was a missing line final Button LogOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogOut); i deleted it by fault am so srry and thnx alot for your help

Answer (score 0):

In login activity onLoginClick:

```
startActivity(usersActivity);
finish();
```

In UsersActivity onLogoutClick:

```
startActivity(loginActivity);
finish();
```

Comment: when i put finish() after the startActivity in the logIn activity the app crash when i click logIn

Comment: can you please paste the error log . As ideally this should not cause problem .

Comment: am not getting any error, the only thing happens is that i get a message telling me that the app has stop working but no error record and when i take off the onClickListener of the log out btn everything works fine

Comment: but when i put finish() even without the onClick Listener the app stop working when i press log In as if the app finish the login activity even before loging in